# Returning subclass of DataContract

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have a DataContract which I use as a return type from a WCF service.

```
[DataContract]
public NameResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However, I want to store additional information on the service side, so I create a subclass:

```
internal ServiceNameResult : NameResult
{
    internal Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

However, it seems I am unable to use instances of this as a result value (the error I get on the client isn't very helpful - Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).

Basically, if I do;

```
NameResult GetName() 
{
    NameResult result = {...}
    return result;
}
```

Then it works, but if I do;

```
NameResult GetName()
{
    ServiceNameResult result = {...}
    return result;
}
```

It doesn't. I don't really want to have to copy the properties from the ServiceNameResult to a new NameResult. Hopefully there is a way to make this work?

I've already put [IgnoreDataMember] on the subclass, but that makes no difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to approach this problem.  You could use composition to achieve what you're looking for:

```
internal class ServiceNameResult
{
    object OtherInformation { get; set; }

    NameResult Result { get; set; }
}
```

So your internal service implementation can hold a reference to the client return object as well as additional information, but you don't pollute your interface.

Comment: Normally, I'd have done this, but the data contracts are a little more functional than this and I need to be able to transparently use instances that come into the service (i.e. NameResult) with the instances in the service (ServiceNameResult) as if they're the same.

Comment: @user302699 - Is it feasible in your scenario to move the behavior that is currently in your data contracts to extension methods or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define ServiceNameResult as a [known type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: But the subclass is internal, and needs to stay that way. The superclass (NameResult) is defined in a separate shared assembly